# Do I need a copy constructor to modify static member when push_back into a vector?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Imagine the following class:

```
class test
{
private:
static int counter;
//some stuff
public:
test() {++counter;};
~test() {--counter;};
};
```

My problem is the following:
If I `push_back` into a vector:

```
std::vector<test> tests;
tests.push_back(test());
```

At this point I want my counter to mark `1` as I have a total of 1 elements created. The problem is that it marks 0.

My guess is that I create the object, then copy it into the vector, and then the object gets destroyed.

Do I have another option other than create a copy constructor?

Comment: @NathanOliver You dont have `--counter` in the destructor

Comment: Well, you didn't either until just now.  If this is your setup then yes, the copy constructor needs to do the same thing your constructor does.  Unless you switch to using `emplace_back`

Comment: I have to ask, but what is the purpose of the `counter` here?  If it is to count the number of objects created, you need to create copy constructors and possibly move constructor.  What you've implemented is inadequate.  Even if the counter is to count the number of objects, for what purpose do you need that information for?  (Asking, as this could potentially be an [X/Y issue](http://xyproblem.info/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter should match the number of objects your program has at any given time. Every destruction reduces the number of objects, and that's why there is a `--counter`. Also, every constructor creates one more object increasing the total number of objects, so every constructor should have a `++counter`.

A copy constructor (defaulted or not) creates a new object. So obviously, you must make sure that the copy constructor has a `++counter`. For that you must implement a copy constructor.

If you don't define this copy constructor, then `push_back` runs a copy constructor, creating a new object. But with a defaulted copy constructor, the counter is left intact. Eventually the temporary, which is passed to `push_back` is deleted and the counter becomes `0` despite having an object in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I did little trick about your code

```
class test
{
    private:
    static int counter;
    //some stuff
    public:
    test() {
        ++counter;
        cout<<"constructor "<<endl;
    }
    ~test() {
        --counter;
        cout<<"Destructors"<<endl;
    }
};

int test::counter = 0;

int main(void) 
{ 
    std::vector<test> tests;
    tests.push_back(test());
    cout<<tests[0].counter<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
constructor 
Destructors
0
Destructors
```

1. create a test object (++0 = 1)
2. vector copies references to previous objects
3. vector delete the object that it created (--1 = 0)
4. print counter
5. original object deleted

It's call [Shallow Copy Constructor](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/copy-constructor-in-cpp.php)